# How can I prevent the horizontal alienation of TextBoxes on generated report (SSRS)?

Tags: reporting-services, textbox

I set up my TextBoxes to be close together:

[image: ~designTimeGenerated.png]

Yet when the report is generated, they are barely in the same zip code:

[image]

How can I prevent this AWOListic behavior of the ExecutionTime (and, to a lesser extent, UserID) TextBoxes?

### UPDATE

I'm sure the answer is correct, but getting it to work is another matter. When I right-click in the Textbox and select "", I am able to navigate to the Date format I want:

[image]

...but after I mash the "OK" button, I get:

[image]

So it's another case of non-intuitive/non-user-friendly software. I guess the Redmondians are standing in the bread line and can't afford to make it work as it should.

Comment: Is your field alignment set to right perchance?

Comment: Ah - TextAlign was set to Default, which is apparently Right. I changed it to left. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use 1 text box, just right click inside textbox select "create placeholder"..

[image]

Comment: How much will that cost me?